# Pinterest doesn't load properly when I use a mobile broadband dongle

Tags: pinterest

**Please - what steps should I take to trouble shoot this?**

I use Pinterest on Google Chrome, on Snow Leopard.

It works fine when I access from an Internet cafe.

But when I try to connect using my mobile broadband dongle (Huawei e173 on T Mobile in the UK) it doesn't fully load.  Everything else (all other websites I try) appears to work fine.

See these screenshots - you can see that the pinterest website partially loads, and Chrome thinks it's finished, but there's no content in the main screen.  Clearing cache and force reload makes no difference.

You can see here that I've selected the architecture category.  Normally I'd get lots of pins to look at, but not when I connect via broadband dongle.

**Please - what steps should I take to trouble shoot this?**

(There doesn't seem to be anything on the Pinterest support site about this yet.)

[image: broken pinterest]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HTTPS instead of HTTP to load Pinterest. The certificate will throw warnings but that is because they aren't securing their images.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has also happened to me, and changing it to HTTPS didn't work. Alternatively, if you click on settings and then on search privacy click 'on' , it should fix it.